# Read string next to another in c

Tags: c, memory, preload

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char text[] = "PASS_KEY";

  printf("Hey\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I know those strings are literally next one to one in memory.
How can I redefine printf with LD_Preload to read `text`?

Comment: *next one to one*, "Hey" following *text*?

Comment: Not clear for me. What you means with LD_Preload to read text?

Comment: [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)

Answer (score 2):

Defining a shim `printf` to dump memory around the pointer it is passed is not a difficult task:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dump(const char *data) {
    fwrite(data - 32, 1, 64, stdout);
}

int printf(const char *data, ...) {
    dump(data);
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -c -fPIC print.c -o print.o
ld -shared -o libprint.so print.o
```

and now you can `LD_PRELOAD=./libprint.so ./program` and get the key. Or you could... You have a few separate problems here.

GCC at least optimizes a `printf` with no placeholders in the format string to a `puts`. So what gets called by your program is not `printf`. Well, let's shim `puts` too:

```
int puts(const char *data) {
    dump(data);
}
```

now you get the dump on screen:

```
..............Hey........
```

so it's working. But there's no trace of the key. Why?

Because `text` is a local variable (array) and `"Hey\n"` is a constant string. So `text` is allocated on the stack and `"Hey\n"` in the constant pool, which is not exactly "next to it". Your assumption is wrong. If you modify the program as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char text[] = "PASS_KEY";
  char format[] = "Hey\n";

  printf(format);
  return 0;
}
```

which, incidentally, is a thing you **WOULD THINK TWICE BEFORE DOING** because using non-constant format strings for `printf` is B.A.D. in most cases, it will work:

```
............Hey
PASS_KEY.
```

Success!